# Apex Triggers and Order of Execution doc - System Validations

Tags: before-trigger, required-field

I thought I knew this stuff but in [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.222.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) Step 2

> 2. Loads the new record field values from the request and overwrites the old values.
>
> If the request came from a standard UI edit page, Salesforce runs system validation to check the record for:
>
> - Compliance with layout-specific rules
> - Required values at the layout level and field-definition level
> - Valid field formats
> - Maximum field length
>
> When the request comes from other sources, such as an **Apex application or a SOAP API call**, Salesforce **validates only the foreign keys**. Before executing a trigger, Salesforce verifies that any custom foreign keys do not refer to the object itself.

Based on my tests (`FldOfLen10__c`, `Account.Name`, `Contact.Email`)

- From execute anonymous
- From workbench REST POST *(I did not try SOAP)*

> Salesforce validates field lengths, required fields, and field formats **BEFORE** the triggers execute.

I can appreciate how Salesforce needs to reverify these at the conclusion of the before trigger (Step 4).

I looked back at the doc all the way to V30.0 and the same language is present for Step 2.

> Is this a doc bug or where am I wrong?

Comment: I tested it as well, and can confirm that system validations run prior to Before Triggers in Exec Anon and in Async context (@future), not allowing you to fix bad input programmatically.   Tested with API v50, Field - Account Name being too long.